# Whenever my program crashes in eclipse it stays running in the background

Tags: java, eclipse

It is really frustrating especially when I am working with sockets. Anyone know how to fix this? I constantly go into the task manager...

Comment: It crashes *and* keeps running?

Comment: @CodeCamper It happens to me as well from time to time when a program I am working on crashes and the only solution I've come across is what you have said, go to the task manager. I've even needed to restart the computer once or twice when it gets really slow.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most likely reason for this is a thread which does not terminate. This might be caused by the thread waiting for a time out, but a number of other reasons might prevent the thread from exiting as well.

I suggest you connect jvisualvm (part of the jdk, located in the bin folder) to your application and investigate what part of your application stays alive.

*Edit:* If your application runs in your systems default vm, you should see it in jvisualvm out of the box. But if you are using different vms, you have to start the application with appropriate parameters in order to connect jvisualvm to it.

This [short guide](https://visualvm.java.net/jmx_connections.html) explains the settings pretty well.

Comment: the problem is this ONLY occurs in Eclipse, if I run the application outside of Eclipse and it crashes the same exact way the entire program just turns off.

Comment: Can you explain how the program crashes? Are we talking about an uncaught exception?